# Problemas con Promises dentro de Array.map() (JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

EL escenario es el siguiente, tengo un array con ids con los que puedo retirar informacion de una api.

EL problema es que dicha api tiene un rate limit por lo que cada vez que hago una query a dicha api, almaceno los datos en una BD de tal manera que verifico si ya tengo los datos en la base de datos y los proporciono de esta de tal manera que evito querys inecesarias.

Dicho esto, desde el backend siempre indico en la variable count, si se ha tenido que hacer query o viene de base de datos.

En caso de que sea true, hago "contador++" y comparo con el cap para ver si lo he pasado.

El problema es que se ejecutan todas las peticiones de golpe y la verificacion del "if(contador

```js
let contador = 0;
let cap = 10;
await Promise.all(matchList.map(async (g,i)=>{
       
        if(contador<cap){
             await ApiComponent.getGameData(g.gameId).
                then(d=>{
                    //Desde backend se manda count true en caso de que se retire de api y no de base de datos
                    if(d.data.count){
                      contador++;
                     
                    }
                    temp.push(d.data.match);
                    
                }).catch(e=>console.log("Error en fetch Game data"))
        }else{console.log("cap")}
    }))
```

¿Estoy entendiendo algo mal?

Tenia entendido que con el await no deberia de seguir ejecutandose el codigo.

Un saludo!

Comment: Te puse un +1 porque siendo usuario nuevo hiciste una pregunta totalmente valida y aparte bien formateada en lo que cabe, felicidades, respecto a... ´tengo entendido que con await no deberia ejecutarse el codigo´, enrealidad await no es un return, await simplemente pausa la ejecucion del codigo y luego la resume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un error bastante común cuando se trata con la asincronicidad en Javascript, y no es muy sencillo de explicar, lamentablemente.

Lo que realmente hace *keyword* `await` es reservar un espacio en la *call stack* para ejecutar todo el código que va a continuación una vez la `Promise` se resuelve. Digamos que, virtualmente, se crea una función con todo ese contenido.

> La *call stack* es una estructura de datos que registra básicamente en qué parte del programa estamos. Si entramos en una función, la colocamos en la parte superior de la pila.

Cuando hablamos de ejecución asíncrona en Javascript, se añade el concepto del *event loop*. El *event loop* se encargará de estar pendiente a todas las *callbacks* en espera para colocarlas en el *call stack*.
De ese modo, conseguimos que el *script* siga ejecutándose mientras estamos esperando a una respuesta (de la base de datos, petición HTTP, evento de UI, etc...).
[Aquí](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-event-loop/) dejo una serie de lecturas muy interesantes para profundizar sobre el tema, también un [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrNQS8J67zc) excelente.

Quiero disculparme si estoy haciendo esta respuesta demasiado extensa, pero necesito dejar claros estos conceptos.

Con lo mencionado,

```
const delay = millis => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, millis);
    });

delay(1000).then(_ => {
    console.log(`Done.`);
});
console.log(`End?`);
```

... a nadie le soprende que se imprime primero el `End?`, después el `Done.` (un segundo después).

Cuando ejecutamos la función `map` de un *array* y tenemos dentro una `Promise`, esa `Promise` se efectúa, pero se resuelve después.

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
arr.map(e => {
    console.log(`Entry for ${e}`);
    delay(100).then(_ => {
        console.log(`Resolved for ${e}`);
    });
});
```

Como en el ejemplo anterior, creo que no sorprende a nadie que el *output* sea

> Entry for 0
>   Entry for 1
>   Entry for 2
>   Resolved for 0
>   Resolved for 1
>   Resolved for 2

Vamos a refactorizarlo para usarlo con `async`/`await`.

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
arr.map(async e => {
    console.log(`Entry for ${e}`);
    await delay(100);
    console.log(`Resolved for ${e}`);
});
```

> Entry for 0
>   Entry for 1
>   Entry for 2
>   Resolved for 0
>   Resolved for 1
>   Resolved for 2

¡Y *voilà*! Tenemos exactamente el mismo *output*. Quizás esto sorprenda a algunos. Quizás no.

Si nos ponemos a pensar, `map` tiene por dentro un *loop* que iterará sobre cada elemento del *array*. Para cada uno, ejecutará la función que le pasemos como argumento dándonos el valor del elemento en cada iteración.
El caso es que `map` nunca va a esperar a nuestra función a que ejecute. La función `map` no es asíncrona.
Al final de la respuesta vemos una aproximación a la implementación del `map` para verlo mejor.

**Vamos a emular tu escenario**.

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
const constrained = (arr, max) => {
    let count = 0;

    return () => {
        arr.map(async e => {
            if (count < max) {
                console.log(`Entry for ${e}`);
                await delay(1000);
                ++count;

                console.log(`Resolved for ${e}. Count is now ${count}`);
            }
        });
    }
}

const onlyTwo = constrained(arr, 2);
onlyTwo();
```

Como vemos, antes de "awaitear" la `Promise`, hacemos el *check* con el conteo. El *output* es el siguiente.

> Entry for 0
>   Entry for 1
>   Entry for 2
>   Resolved for 0. Count is now 1
>   Resolved for 1. Count is now 2
>   Resolved for 2. Count is now 3

Se han ejecutado todas las `Promise`.
¿Por qué? Lo hemos visto antes, cada una de las funciones en la iteración del `map` se ha ejecutado "instantáneamente", y la variable `count` se ha actualizado una vez se han resuelto las `Promise`.
Por lo tanto, en el momento de ejecutar la condición en el `if`, `count` aún no se había modificado, seguía siendo `0`. Todas las condiciones se cumplieron.

**¿Qué podemos hacer para solucionar el problema?**
Bueno una solución muy inmediata sería poner la condición una vez la `Promise` se ha resuelto.

```
const constrained = (arr, max) => {
    let count = 0;

    return () => {
        arr.map(async e => {
            console.log(`Entry for ${e}`);
            await delay(1000);

            if (count++ < max)
                console.log(`Resolved for ${e}. Count is now ${count}`);
        });
    }
}
```

De esta forma, tenemos el *output* que buscábamos.

> Entry for 0
>   Entry for 1
>   Entry for 2
>   Resolved for 0. Count is now 1
>   Resolved for 1. Count is now 2

Sin embargo, todas las `Promise` fueron resueltas. Esto supondría, en un escenario real, que se han ejecutado todas las llamadas HTTP, las *queries* a la base de datos, eventos, ... pero sólo hemos tratado el resultado de éstas `max` veces.
Tampoco es lo que necesitamos.

Deberemos iterar sobre el *array* y, en cada iteración, esperar a la resolución de la `Promise` para poder actualizar la variable `count`.
Para ello, y des de la *ES2018* de Javascript, podemos usar el [`for await ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for-await...of).
Con el `for` asíncrono, se hace un `await` en cada iteración.

```
const constrained = (arr, max) => {
    let count = 0;

    return async () => {
        for await (let e of arr) {
            if (count++ > max) break;

            console.log(`Entry for ${e}`);
            await delay(100);
            console.log(`Resolved for ${e}`);
        }
    }
}
```

*Et voilà*, el *output* es

> Entry for 0
>   Resolved for 0
>   Entry for 1
>   Resolved for 1

Resultado esperado. El bucle `for` ha esperado a que todas las `Promise` dentro de él se resuelvan antes de iterar al siguiente elemento del *array*.

**Solución en tu escenario**

```
let contador = 0;
let cap = 10;
for await (let g of matchList) {
    if (contador < cap) {
        try {
            const { data } = await ApiComponent.getGameData(g.gameId);
            const { count, match } = data;
            if (count) {
                contador++;
            }

            temp.push(match);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(`Error en fetch Game data`, e);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("cap");
        break;
    }
}
```

Algunas cosas a comentar aquí.

- La sintaxis `async`/`await` nos habilita el `try`/`catch` en caso de que una `Promise` dé error (llame internamente a su función `reject`). De este modo el código queda un poco más limpio.
- Al estar usando la *keyword* `await` en el `for`, la función que contenga el *loop* asíncrono deberá ser `async`, también. Es decir, este código devuelve implícitamente una `Promise`, que se resolverá una vez el *loop* termine (ya sea porque se ha iterado sobre todos los elementos, o se ha llamado al `break`).
- He añadido el `break` en caso de que se excede el límite de capacidad. De este modo nos ahorramos iteraciones.
- En el `catch`, en vez de un `console.log` llamo a `console.error`, que está pensado para este tipo de casos. El mensaje aparece en rojo en la consola. También he añadido que se imprima el error, de modo que se pueda ver qué sucedió.

Espero que sirva.

---

Lo prometido es deuda, no me olvido.
Vamos a ver qué aproximación hacemos de la función `map` del *prototype* `Array`.

```
const map = (arr, callback) => {
    let stack = [];
    for (let e of arr) {
        const r = callback(e);
        stack = [...stack, r];
    }

    return stack;
}
```

Esta es la aproximación. Obviamente, la función `map` pasa como argumento no sólo el elemento actual, sinó también el índice y el *array* actual.
Pero con esta aproximación podemos jugar. ¿Cómo la podríamos hacer asíncrona? Haciendo uso del `for await ... of`, nuevamente.

```
const mapAsync = async (arr, callback) => {
    let stack = [];
    for await (let e of arr) {
        const r = await callback(e);
        stack = [...stack, r];
    }

    return stack;
}
```

Inclusive, si fuera algo que necesitásemos a menudo, podríamos añadirlo al *prototype* de `Array` para usarlo con cualquier array que queramos de una forma más cómoda.

```
Array.prototype.mapAsync = async function(callback) {
    let stack = [];
    for await (let e of this) {
        const r = await callback(e);
        stack = [...stack, r];
    }

    return stack;
}
```

Podemos ver ahora el ejemplo de antes que usábamos el `map` de `Array` y no nos funcionaba. Si usamos nuestro `mapAsync`, tenemos el resultado esperado.

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
const constrained = (arr, max) => {
    let count = 0;

    return () => {
        arr.mapAsync(async e => {
            if (count < max) {
                console.log(`Entry for ${e}`);
                await delay(1000);
                ++count;

                console.log(`Resolved for ${e}. Count is now ${count}`);
            }
        });
    }
}

const onlyTwo = constrained(arr, 2);
onlyTwo();
// Entry for 0
// Resolved for 0. Count is now 1
// Entry for 1
// Resolved for 1. Count is now 2
```

De nuevo, espero que sirva y ayude a aclarar ciertos conceptos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme en profundidad el escenario, seguire tu recomendacion de añadirlo al prototype. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Te haz pulido bastante en tu respuesta,  esta mas que excelente +1.

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas el `await` dentro de tu promise, puesto que al usar `await` no puedes usar `.then` y `.catch` si no directamente recibir una respuesta o un error, es decir, cuando tu **no** usas `await` tendrias que hacerlo exactamente como lo tienes pero sin el **await**:

```
ApiComponent.getGameData(g.gameId)
.then(d=>{
      //Desde backend se manda count true en caso de que se retire de api y no de base de datos
      if(d.data.count){
          contador++;

      }
      temp.push(d.data.match);

}).catch(e=>console.log("Error en fetch Game data"));
```

Y no tendrias que poner entonces tu funcion dentro de la promise como `async`.

en caso de querer usar `await`, entonces aquello de arriba se traduce a esto:

```
try{
   const d = await ApiComponent.getGameData(g.gameId);

   if(d.data.count){
      contador++;
   }
   temp.push(d.data.match);
}catch(e){
   console.log("Error en fetch Game data");
}
```

No se sabe que contiene tu variable `matchList` por lo cual no puedo ayudar mucho mas... sin embargo esto de que "se ejecutan todas las peticiones de golpe" debe ser algún control que esta fallando en el backend, puesto que `Promise.all` a menos de que estes usando `nodejs` no tiene el poder para hacer `paralelismo` (paralelismo significa ejecutar varias tareas simultáneamente), es decir, tus promises se ejecutan en un orden y hasta que no termine una no se ejecuta la otra, y el orden es de acuerdo al orden del array.

De hecho, no estoy seguro, pero una posible razón de este inconveniente, es el hecho de que dentro de `map` estas ejecutando tus `promises` y pues `map` es sincrono y las promises son asíncronas... en cuyo caso  puede ayudar el hecho de no hacer esperar a `map`, asi que tendrias que reformular las comprobaciones que haces... puesto que como estas ejecutando las `promises` a la vez de cada iteracion de `map` entonces `Promise.all` seria casi instantaneo cuando se ejecute, puesto que ya todas las promises habrán sido resueltas para el momento en que map termine, tu mismo las estas ejecutando dentro de cada iteracion de map al hacer `await`:

```
await ApiComponent.getGameData(g.gameId).
then(d=>{
    ...
}
```

Puede este ser el inconveniente.