# ¿Como puedo crear una pausa del programa en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Quiero hacer una función que cuando se ejecute las acciones tengan una pausa como de tres segundos entre si por si no me entieden he intentado esto:

```
  function allplay(){
           word.play();
           word2.play();
           word3.play();
           word4.play();
           word5.play();
           word6.play();
           word7.play();
           word8.play();
           word9.play();
           word10.play();
           word11.play();
           word12.play();
         }
```

Comment: un await no tiene nada que ver con lo que intentas hacer, https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona aqui podras ver las funciones async await del nuevo javascript

Answer (score 3):

Para poder "esperar" el tiempo que quieras entre instrucción e instrucción, debes usar las `Promise`.

```
const delay = millis => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, millis);
    });
```

Esta función resolverá la `Promsise` pasados `millis` milisegundos.
Si se llama des de una función asíncrona y se espera a la resolución con un `await`, puede darse la ilusión de que el programa "se pausa".

```
async function allPlay() {
   word.play();
   await delay();
   word.play();
   await delay();

   // ...
}
```

Te podría interesar este [*post*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355134/problemas-con-promises-dentro-de-array-map-js/355197#355197) donde lo explico más detenidamente.

Y, por supuesto, la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) las funciones `async`.

Sólo para completar, aquí va una idea para estandarizar esto y que te sea más cómodo.

```
const interLock = async (fn, repeat, millis, ...args) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < repeat -1; ++i) {
        fn(...args);
        await delay(millis);
    }
    fn(...args);
}
```

Donde `fn` será la función a invocar (en tu caso `word.play`),
`repeat` es el número de veces que quieres que se repita la función,
`millis` el tiempo de espera entre función y función, en milisegundos,
`args` la lista de argumentos para pasar a la función, si los hubiera.

```
const obj = {
    play: (arg1, arg2) => console.log(`Ejecutando`, arg1, arg2)
}

interLock(obj.play, 3, 1000, `con múltiples`, `parámetros`);
// Ejecutando con múltiples parámetros
// Ejecutando con múltiples parámetros
// Ejecutando con múltiples parámetros
```

que es equivalente a

```
const obj = {
    play: (arg1, arg2) => console.log(`Ejecutando`, arg1, arg2)
}

interLock(() => obj.play(`con múltiples`, `parámetros`), 3, 1000);
```

Espero que sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer una pausa puedes intentar ocupar la ejecución de javascript durante X tiempo. ¿como puedo hacerlo?, usando ciclos.

Usando el ciclo for, podemos lograr ocupar el programa hasta que se termine de recorrer el ciclo.

**El funcionamiento seria el siguiente:**

A. Tomar el tiempo del momento en que inicia la pausa (tiempo_inicio).

B. luego ir pidiendo el tiempo (tiempo_actual).

C. Calcular la diferencia entre el (inicio) y (actual).

D. Verificar que sea mayor o igual a la espera.

En código seria:

```
function wait(espera_segundos) {
  espera = espera_segundos * 1000
  const tiempo_inicio = Date.now();
  let tiempo_actual= null;
  do {
    tiempo_actual= Date.now();
  } while (tiempo_actual - tiempo_inicio < espera);
}

console.log("Hello");
wait(20);
console.log("World!");
```

**¿Como funciona?**

1. Asignamos la fecha de inicio al llamar la función.
2. Creamos una variable que guardara el tiempo actual.
3. Luego haremos un do/while, que verifica que nuestro tiempo transcurrido sea menor que la espera
4. Luego en el ciclo le asignamos al tiempo actual el tiempo actual transcurrido, y hacemos el calculo.
5. Al restar fechas en javascript, esta se realizan en mili segundos, sin embargo la funcion puede recibir la espera en segundos y dentro de ella multiplicarla para trabajar en mili segundos.
6. Una vez la resta es mayor a la espera (primero sera igual), se romperá el ciclo y la ejecución de javascript continuara